# Oracle SQL statement to find all Emails that start with non Aplha/Numeric characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to call back all rows who's email starts with a character which is not AlphaNumeric.
The line I am trying to use in the statement is 
    `REGEXP_LIKE (SUBSTR(hcp_email.email_address,1,2), '![%a-zA-Z%]')`
This does not bring back the relevant lines.
I am able to bring back results with the below but this is not as practical as using a catch all range of text and numbers to ignore.
    `REGEXP_LIKE (SUBSTR(hcp_email.email_address, 1,2), '[":., ]')`

Ideally I would like to use a NOT LIKE statement with a range a-z 0-9.

Comment: So, did you try `REGEX_LIKE(hcp_email.email_address, '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]')`?

Comment: `P` got lost from the comment above, surely it must be `REGEXP_LIKE`

Comment: Thanks for your response this worked for me :) I had not used `^` I had tried to use `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to embed a SUBSTR call.  Just anchor the regex to the start of the string, and look at the first character.  This example uses the POSIX shorthand for readability.

```
where regexp_like(hcp_email.email_address, '^[^[:alnum:]]');
```

EDIT - Added regex explanation

```
^         - Anchor to the start of the string 
[         - Start a character class 
^         - Inside of a character class this means NOT
[:alnum:] - POSIX shorthand for an alphanumeric (A-Za-z0-9)
]         - End character class (the character class describes 1 character)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am quite new so will spend sometime looking at how the anchor works for future use :) certainly would be better this way than adding the SUBSTR !

Comment: You bet, edited to give a more detailed explanation of the regex.